# Xcode History (back/forward) Keyboard Shortcut?

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

## Back Arrow Broken In Xcode?

Is there  keyboard command to go back/forward one **file** at a time.

Xcode 3.2 *changed the behavior* of Cmd-Opt <-- and -->. As noted in another question, they do not operate on a file level like in previous versions of Xcode, but on an "edit point", making it cumbersome to flip through a list of files (the quick way to do it, since Xcode does not support Tabs, as in Eclipse).

Rob Keniger found a partial solution that he noted in another post:

> "Hold down the option key while you click the forward/backward arrows ..."

But this requires fiddling with the mouse. Is there any way to do it with the **keyboard only**?

**EDIT**:
Later versions of Xcode (v7.2+) now have a Navigate menu (and it changes the keyboard shortcuts yet again): [image]

Comment: There is literally 'Navigate' Menu, but hey thanks helped

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Beginning in XCode 3.2.3, the following key sequence works:

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>

Without the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, it just goes back to the previous cursor position. Adding <kbd>Shift</kbd> jumps to the previous file (next file, in combination with <kbd>→</kbd>).

Comment: why can't you, the owner, switch your right answer? the answer below is more appropriate!

Answer (score 214):

In XCode 4.4 the following sequence works:

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>

and it operates on a file level.

Comment: Cmd+Ctrl+(right arrow) also works. These are called "Go Back" and "Go Forward" in the Key Bindings section in case you want to remap them.

Comment: You have no idea how much time this is gonna save me! i already use Cmd+Ctrl+up  to switch between .h and .m

Comment: @stevo.mit - can't seem to make it work in xcode 7... (ever since I switched it's just not working) - any idea why?

Comment: @Boaz Please check your Xcode shortcuts in Preferences to make sure there is no other conflicting command for the same key combination. Also, sometimes the shortcut for moving between .h and .m files stops working for me but when i manually move to the other file or move to a different class, it starts working again.

Comment: Mark this as the accepted answer! Works like a charm.

Comment: I feel obligated to say: this also works in Xcode 8.

Answer (score 21):

On Xcode 8 I use 2 fingers left / right

Comment: I used to find this really annoying at the beginning. Oh boy, the time has really changed.

Answer (score 9):

Navigation shortcuts for Xcode 
[image]

Comment: thank you @Wasim. Where did you find this info from?